# Как организовать работу с буфером обмена python?

Tags: python

Допросы гугла не дали результатов (если что, у меня windows).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

С помощью Tkinter.

Добавить в буфер обмена

```
from tkinter import Tk

tk = Tk()
tk.withdraw()
tk.clipboard_clear()
tk.clipboard_append('This is clipboard contents.')
tk.update()
tk.destroy()
```

А извлечь из буфера обмена

```
cb = tk.clipboard_get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Также можно с использованием библиотеки `win32clipboard`

Получить данные из буфера обмена:

```
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

Положить данные в буфер обмена

```
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
win32clipboard.SetClipboardText('testing 123')
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```